Highcharts organization chart sibling node
I am playing with this demo https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/organization-chart
And trying to add a sibling to for instance the CEO node.
What I'd like is basically a line out from the right or left side of the CEO node to a new node called simply Test.
But when I add a Test node and set the relation to ['CEO', 'Test'], and I set both node levels to be the same (2), it still looks like the new Test node is a child of the Board node since the line is coming from Board.
Is there a way to achieve a straight line out from CEO to Test?
Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zL3k4a8x/

I'm afraid it's not possible using the Highcharts API.
